# finding the size of an unknown array in C

Tags: c

We have been  given a large  array of unknown size with elements given , is there any function or something other through which we can find the size of that array in language C
int a[]={4,6,4,26,3,2,5,7,3,7,3,2,5,4,6,3,7,232,6,32,6,3,7,3,6,2,5,7,3,6,3,6,36,3,67,23,6};

Comment: Given how? In an envelope?

Comment: int a[]={4,6,4,26,3,2,5,7,3,7,3,2,5,4,6,3,7,232,6,32,6,3,7,3,6,2,5,7,3,6,3,6,36,3,67,23,6};

Comment: The sizeof() function is your friend.

Comment: This size is known.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
It does not help either
int main()
{int a[]={4,6,4,26,3,2,5,7,3,7,3,2,5,4,6,3,7,232,6,32,6,3,7,3,6,2,5,7,3,6,3,6,36,3,67,23,6};
printf("%d",sizeof(a));
}

Comment: In this way you get the size in bytes, to print the number of elements use `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a));`

Comment: @Azam It is known, it just isn't readily apparent.  By contrast, if you were to pass that array in as an argument to a function, then as far as that function was concerned, the size of the array would be unknown as it would decay to a pointer and thus `sizeof` would give you the size of the pointer and not the number of bytes in the array.

Comment: if you dont have an array, but just a degenerate array, which doesn't have a length you will have to null terminate it and iterate it

Comment: Upvoting to offset some of the unexplained, and thus unhelpful, downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

The size in bytes you can get by

```
sizeof(a);
```

The number of elements in that array you can get by

```
sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
```